# How to draw a projectile following specific XY coordinates?

Tags: java, javafx

I am developing a game where I am moving a projectile through a specific path. I have got the X and Y for each point in time, but how do I animate it so that the projectiles move from one point to another following the calculated path?

Comment: Show your code, what you have tried and where you have problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you can compute the position x(t) and y(t) of your projectile at any time t then using an AnimationTimer is probably the easiest and most flexible way to animate your projectile. There numerous tutorials out there which give you the details. For example https://dzone.com/articles/using-javafx-animationtimer